# extracting value from a model in exists_expr_vector_example

Tags: z3

In the `exists_expr_vector_example()` function from the file `example.cpp`, when I am trying to extract a value of a variable, say `xs[1]`, using the code:

```
    solver s(c);
    s.add(ex); s.check();
    model m = s.get_model();
    cout<<m.eval(xs[1]);
```

I am getting an output of `x_1`, instead of the value of the variable `x_1`. How should we approach this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the exists example, the variables are bound.
You can assert 'b' instead of 'ex'. In 'b', the variables in xs are not bound and the model will assign values for free variables. Models do not assign values for bound variables.

```
solver s(c);
s.add(b); s.check();
model m = s.get_model();
std::cout<<m.eval(xs[1]) << "\n";
```